# Why can't upper-case letters be used for pattern matching for define values?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Why can I use lower-case letters for names:

```
val (a, bC) = (1, 2)

(1, 2) match {
  case (a, bC) => ???
}
```

and can't use upper-case letters:

```
/* compile errors: not found: value A, BC  */
val (A, BC) = (1, 2)

/* compile errors: not found: value A, BC  */
(1, 2) match {
  case (A, BC) => ???
}
```

I'm using `scala-2.11.17`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the designers of Scala preferred to allow identifiers starting with upper-case letters to be used like this (and allowing both would be confusing):

```
val A = 1

2 match {
  case A => true
  case _ => false
} // returns false, because 2 != A
```

Note that with lower case you'll get

```
val a = 1

2 match {
  case a => true
  case _ => false
} // returns true
```

because `case a` binds a *new* variable called `a`.

One very common case is

```
val opt: Option[Int] = ...

opt match {
  case None => ... // you really don't want None to be a new variable here
  case Some(a) => ...
}
```

Comment: Similarly upper case helps with case classes: `trait A; case class B(v: Int) extends A; case object C extends A; (C: A) match { case C => "object"; case B(_) => "case class"; case o => "other" }`. `case o` will compile and `case O` won't.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that if you're stuck with a lowercase name as in your second example, you can make it work by putting backticks around the name: ``case `a` => true``.