# why can't we have capital letters in tuple variable declaration in scala

Tags: scala, variables, tuples

Why can't we have Capital letter in a tuple variable, As I create a `TestData` it throws an error

```
val (trainingData, TestData): Tuple2[RDD[LabeledPoint],RDD[LabeledPoint]] = (splits(0), splits(1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are not creating a ordinary variable in your case.

```
val (trainingData, TestData) =
```

This is deconstructiong the right-hand side expression using the pattern matching on left-hand side. So the variables in **pattern matching** expressions must start with a lower-case letter.

```
val (trainingData, TestData) = (split(0), split(1))
```

will be equivalent to

```
(split(0), split(1)) match {
      case (trainingData, TestData) => (trainingData, TestData)
    }
```

Which tries to assign the two split values to trainingData, TestData which fails because it always accepts only with the lowercase variable at starting.

Rather, this will works fine

```
val (trainingData, testData) = (split(0), split(1))
```

This means,

```
(split(0), split(1)) match {
      case (trainingData, testData) => (trainingData, testData)
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your explain ,but why case required  lowercase variable at starting?

Comment: lowercase variable are used to bind the variables with value where as Capital variables are used to match with the variable names.This helps you to understand more  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217913/why-cant-upper-case-letters-be-used-for-pattern-matching-for-define-values

Answer (score 2):

In Scala you can create variables with a leading uppercase letter. (It's not recommended, but it can be done.)

```
val TestCnt = 7
```

But you can't do that when creating variables via pattern matching.

```
val (ch, num)       = ('x', 17)  // OK
val (Run, distance) = (true, 5)  // error: not found: value Run
```

Why is that? It's because the compiler needs to make a distinction between "constant patterns" and "variable patterns." This is explained in some detail in [Section 15.2, "Kinds of Patterns"](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#15.2) [PiS ([1st Edition](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/))], but the gist of it is that a leading uppercase letter is considered a constant, meaning that the pattern must match this value exactly, and a leading lowercase letter is considered a variable, which will match any value and that variable is also bound to the value.

```
someTuple match {
  case ('t', 42)    => /*will match only if both elements match these values*/
  case (_, TestCnt) => /*will match only if 2nd element same value as TestCnt*/
  case (c, n)       => /*will match any 2-ple, variables c,n bound to values*/
}
```

It's worth noting that there is a workaround for the lowercase-is-variable rule (use backticks) but there is no way to sidestep the uppercase-is-constant rule.