# How to use a var from object in match case condition

Tags: scala

I have an object with mutable variables which will be populated using a property file. When I'm trying to use these variables in match condition, I'm getting an error `stable identifier required, but com.zzz.yyy.xxx.Object.Var.toString found.
    case SourceTable(Object.Var.toString) => {`

I also tried using case class but still getting the same error. I need to read the values from property file only and can't be hard-coded in match condition.

Is there a way to do it?

NOTE: I'm new to scala.

Answer (score 1):

Try `case SourceTable(s) if s == Object.Var.toString`.

Basically, you cannot use `var`s (unstable identifier) inside `unapply`, due to what code that would generate.

Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35218246/6345611 (and, particularly, last comment there) might be useful for you.